# Error in GSEA expresion data set file

Tags: gsea

I'm want to perform an GSEA of some RNA-seq data but when I upload the expression data set file this problem appears but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks for your help.

Pol

Error Details

```
---- Full Error Message ----
There were errors: ERROR(S) #:1
Parsing trouble
java.lang.NumberFormatException: ...

---- Stack Trace ----
# of exceptions: 1
------For input string: "description"------
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "description"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.AbstractParser.parseStringToFloat(AbstractParser.java:250)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.AbstractParser.parseFieldsIntoFloatArray(AbstractParser.java:361)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.AbstractParser.parseTextMatrixToDataset(AbstractParser.java:277)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.TxtDatasetParser.parse(TxtDatasetParser.java:108)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserFactory.readDatasetTXT(ParserFactory.java:200)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserFactory.read(ParserFactory.java:758)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserFactory.read(ParserFactory.java:735)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserWorker.doInBackground(ParserWorker.java:53)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show the first few lines of your input files. Given this is a file format error problem, it will help to know the current format of your files.